# "not a smallest response" or "not the smallest response"?

Tags: phrase-choice

You've asked a question on .stack and don't get an answer for 5 straight days. So you say, "Is my question that hard? 5 days and not the smallest response!"

Or should it be "...and not a smallest response!"?

Or "... and not a slightest response!"?

Or "... and not even one response!"?

or should it be something else?

Comment: I wouldn't use *smallest/slightest* because there is no comparison. There just aren't any. So "not a *single* response". "not even one response" is also ok.

Comment: @user3169 - That's an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have in mind a scenario like this:

> We've been discussing these things for weeks now, and we haven't heard **the tiniest peep** out of you. Why are you suddenly objecting?

That pattern using the superlative doesn't adapt very well to an online forum.

Perhaps **briefest** or **most basic** or **most rudimentary** could be used.

> The question was up there for five days without even the briefest answer.
>
> The question was up there for five days without even the most basic answer.
>
> The question was up there for five days without even the most rudimentary answer.

The pattern presents the thing as feeble or meager, the least one could possibly do.

> The question was up there for five days without even the most slapdash answer.
>
> The question was up there for five days without even the most half-baked answer.

Comment: Thank you for all these interesting suggestions. I like "briefest" the most. Could I still use the "there is..." structure with it (like "... and there is not even the briefest answer")?

Comment: Yes, but with a time period I'd use the present perfect:  "... and there has been not even the briefest answer".